# How to select a datalist option

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a registration form and I need to show a secondary choice for users who select a specific option,
do you see where the mistake is?

```html
<div>
  <label for="prof_ecm">Dichiaro di essere:</label>
  <input type="text" list="prof_k" class="form-control" name="prof_ecm" id="prof_ecm" placeholder="* campo obbligatorio" required>
  <datalist id="prof_k">
    <option value="Dipendente" id="dipen" onClick="dip()">
    <option value="Convenzionato">
    <option value="Libero professionista">
    <option value="Privo di occupazione">
    </datalist>
</div>

<div id="div_ente" style="display: none;">
  <label for="ente">Se dipendente, specificare l'Ente</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ente" id="ente">
</div>

<script>
  function dip() {
    var element = document.getElementById("dipen").value;
    if (element = "dipendente") {
      document.getElementById("div_ente").style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If the user always has to select an option, use a `<select>` instead of a `<datalist>` and use an onchange event on the select instead of a onclick on the options. You could probably use a onchange on the input as well if you do want to continue to use a datalist. The clue is, put a change event on the element handling the options, not a click event on the options.

Comment: Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151633/jquery-event-for-html5-datalist-when-item-is-selected-or-typed-input-match-with) for detecting datalist changes

Comment: Your code throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` due to `);` at the end of `dip`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where your problem is but if you want to create groups in `select` tag you can try `<optgroup>` tag ([optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)). It's If you want to change or create new `select` tag you have to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Capture onchange event of input element rather than option element like below,

```js
function dip(element) {
      if (element.value == "Dipendente") {
            document.getElementById("div_ente").style.display = "inline";
      }
  };
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="prof_ecm">Dichiaro di essere:</label>
    <input type="text" list="prof_k" class="form-control" name="prof_ecm" id="prof_ecm" placeholder="* campo obbligatorio" required onchange="dip(this)" >
    <datalist id="prof_k">
        <option value="Dipendente">
        <option value="Convenzionato">
        <option value="Libero professionista">
        <option value="Privo di occupazione">
    </datalist>
</div>

<div id="div_ente" style="display: none;">
    <label for="ente">Se dipendente, specificare l'Ente</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ente" id="ente">
</div>
```

Also you had few typos such as option value is "Dipendente" and you are checking against "dipendente", and the extra closing bracket in the end.